# User defined ordering using MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

This is more of a methodological question. Say I have a table

```
id int auto_increment primary key,
name text not null
```

I have a number of entries which I want to order in some arbitrary way. I could create an interface that allows me to change the order of the names as they would appear on some page. When I read out the entries of the table, they would be ordered according to how I chose. I see three possible approaches. First approach is to add a field

```
order int not null
```

and when I changed the the order, I would have to update every row, or at least every row with ordering higher than the the lowest order I am changing. This seems like the wrong approach, as it would require doing SQL statements in a for loop. The second approach would be to create another table, linked by id

```
id int not null
order int not null
```

but I would run into the same problem here. If I added a name and wanted to put them first, I would have to change the order entry in every row. I could see a possible third approach, which is to store some associations between id and order in a single column, or even in a flat file. I could see using JSON formatting to do this.

My question is this. What is the best way to do this using MySQL and PHP.

Comment: `order` is a reserved word. you'd have to quote that field everywhere you use it. but yep... one way or another you'll have to do a lot of updates to keep this custom ordering field in sync.

Comment: Should be able to accomplish the update without a for loop however.  Not sure I fully follow the use case.  Sounds like a related table is the way to go though.  Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: you can use jQuery UI sortable, and, if you frequently updating order then create another table for id-order

Comment: I'm afraid your first option is the way it's usually done, though not usually intended to be user-updatable. The column name is often called "SortOrder" or "Sequence". Yes, you're in for a lot of updates if it's going to be user-updatable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes a `sorting` column works fine. You don't need a for loop for this.

When doing an insert first increment the other sorting values.

```
UPDATE foo
  SET sorting = sorting + 1
  WHERE sorting >= :sorting;

INSERT INTO foo
  SET name = :name, sorting = :sorting;
```

### [See it work](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/edfb9/1)

On updating set the `sorting` column for the specific record to the new index and increment/decrement the `sorting` for the other records to make a valid sequence.

```
SELECT @old_sorting:=sorting FROM foo WHERE id = :id;
UPDATE foo
  SET sorting = IF(id = :id, :sorting, sorting + IF(@old_sorting > :sorting, 1, -1))
  WHERE sorting BETWEEN LEAST(@old_sorting, :sorting) AND GREATEST(@old_sorting, :sorting);
```

### [See it work](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ea86/2)

*Values of `:id`, `:name` and `:sorting` should be inserted by your mysql lib*

Comment: Oddly enough, I've used this exact method before and for the life of me couldn't think of it when posting my answer! +1 (and removing my much less-helpful post =P)

Comment: This is great. Thank you. Am I wrong in saying that when updating, I could use the same method as your first step for inserting, and then simply update the row of interest, with the consequence that I would develop gaps in the sequence?

Comment: So helpful, you have no idea. Thanks @buck54321 for the question and @Jasny for pointing out the solution by using a `sorting` column. This will save future headaches.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a "weight" int, since Order is a reserved word. As for avoiding the constant updates, you'd have to code some logic to protect against errors, but if you leave the default weight increment something other than 1, you can put things between other items.

IE:

id    weight    item

1     1         something

2     10        somethingElse

add something to be between the two:

id    weight    item

1     1         something

3     5         someOtherThing

2     10        somethingElse

Granted, a second table or simpler structure would be less error prone.